# Firefox 45.0.2 installation on Debian

Tags: firefox, installation

I'm not able to install Firefox 45.0.2 on my Debian system. I have downloaded the `.tar` file and followed the steps. While checking the version, I'm getting the below error. I'm not able to launch Firefox with

```
firefox -v
```

> Error: bash: /usr/bin/firefox: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

I was able to install and use other Firefox versions without any issues.

Comment: Try `file firefox` for checking the file format and also check the file's permissions.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the response. While giving sudo file firefox', I'm getting the below message 'firefox: symbolic link to /opt/firefox/firefox'

Comment: Can anyone help on installing firefox 45.0.2 in rasberrypi. I have followed the below steps but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
sudo apt-get install firefox=45.0.2+build1-0ubuntu1
```